# how to set event click when click editor button

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

i cant call or use event click of editor button that i create. the screen shot for the button is [image: image button]

the code that i make is like this

```
    RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox1 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();        
    EditorButton lp = new EditorButton();
   
    private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Clear();         
          GridView view = sender as GridView;         

            for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {

                if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i) == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
             
                string code = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["code"].ToString();

                if (!repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(code))
                {

                    repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(code);
                }
                                  
            }
        


        if (e.Column.FieldName == "code" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
            {
            
            repositoryItemComboBox1.Buttons.Add(lp);
            repositoryItemComboBox1.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Plus;
            repositoryItemComboBox1.Buttons[1].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Minus;
            
            e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;

            }
```

when i click the minus nothing happen because no handler(event).
what i want is when i click that minus button it clear gridview filter
FYI : iam using devexpress

Comment: Where do you create the event in your code? Presuming that yout minus button is `lp` you should add a handler `lp.Click += lp_clicked` and then define the method `private void lp_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){ // do your things here }`

Comment: the thing is cant call event.click. the editor button dont event have on the toolbox, i define it myself. because when i try to put 'repositoryitemedit' cant convert from control to button

Comment: too bad i cant add handler like that. there fore i must the handler like this ` repositoryItemComboBox1.ButtonClick += repositoryItemComboBox1_ButtonClick;` at least it got me new idea

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to the repositoryItem's ButtonClick event.  In this event, you will know which button has been clicked.  So let's say you create your button this way :

```
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var buttonPlus = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Plus);
        var buttonMinus = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Minus);
        repositoryItemComboBox1.Buttons.Add(buttonPlus);
        repositoryItemComboBox1.Buttons.Add(buttonMinus);
    }
```

In the repositoryItemComboBox1_ButtonClick, you have access to the button properties in the "e" argument.  In this example, i'm using the "Kind" property, but you could use the tag or anything really.

```
    private void repositoryItemComboBox1_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button.Kind == DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Minus)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else if (e.Button.Kind == DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Plus)
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }
```

This is the way I do it.

Comment: how to get repositoryitemcombox1_buttonclick ??. because i define it in 'gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit' to put it in auto filter row.

Comment: when i try to copy paste your `void repositoryitemcombox1_button` click. it got no preferences

Comment: iam not using persistent repository from the toolbox

Comment: now i got it u must define `repositoryItemComboBox1.ButtonClick += repositoryItemComboBox1_ButtonClick` handler so i can use the buttonclick